# How to concatenate this property name in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8, angular14

Trying to pass values by method(function) from one component to another component using extends. But not working. Is it possible by any service?. So How to resolve this issue? If anyone knows please help to find the solutions.

bus.component.ts:

```
export class BusComponent extends CarComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.getValues('2', '5');
  }
  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

car.component.ts:

```
export class CarComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}
  ngOnInit() {}
  getValues(a: any, b: any) {
    console.log(a + '===' + b);
  }
}
```

Demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mb9wjg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcar%2Fcar.component.ts

Comment: It is unclear. Are you trying to pass '2' and '5' from BusComonent to CarComponent?

Comment: @Vega: Yes. You are clear

Comment: But... It is not intended to work like that the inheritance, right?

Comment: It probably doesn't work because the component is not instanciated. Add <app-bus></app-bus> in app.component

Comment: Works fine in the linked Stackblitz..?

Comment: @Mike, they updated the demo

Comment: Gotcha. Ah well, solved I guess?

Comment: @MikeOne: Getting error

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have to use the BusComponent somewhere. If you  don't use this component, the constructor will not be called.
e.g. you can add `<app-bus></app-bus>` in app.component.html and you will see the text in console.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tqg741?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: supper() from BusComponent will call the constructor of CarComponent and because the CarComponent constructor has a parameter you have to call super with httpClient as parameter

Comment: Can you update in the stackblitz?

Comment: Also have to import HttpClientModule in app.module.ts

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-92sird?file=src%2Fapp%2Fshared%2Fbus%2Fbus.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fcar%2Fcar.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: Any other simple way is there to pass the values?

Comment: What do you want to do with these values? Is not clear what you want to achieve. You can declare them as properties in CarComponent and initialize them in BusComponent, but I don't know for what you need these values, depending on what you need them there could be a different way to pass the values.
Also you don't need HttpClient in order to pass the values, but I suppose you need this for something else.

Comment: Getting error. If i use httpclient.   Any ,Other method is there? I mean without extends class ?

Comment: I posted in the previous comments the stackblitz with code where httpclient is not used and is working and another stackblitz code with HttpClient that is working.

Comment: Is it possible by service?

Comment: Better if it by service. you have any idea?

Comment: by creating and using a service is an option also. but why this way from here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tqg741?file=src/app/app.component.html is not good for you?

Comment: and there is also this way by declaring properties in CarComponent https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tqg741?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcar%2Fcar.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fshared%2Fbus%2Fbus.component.ts